# Can questions be watched and then flagged as spam according to agreed upon keywords?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**EDIT** - I've now searched properly..sorry guys :)

I've noticed this question from Kiamlaluno a while back - [Doesn't SE catch spam messages?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/doesnt-se-catch-spam-messages) - is this still the same situation?  Is there still no feature like the following:

Annnnnyway - this morning there have been two questions that I've noticed that are spam directing people to "Watch program x online".  Is there any functionality on SE sites to watch question titles for keywords, and mark as possible spam accordingly?

For example - monitor for the *Watch episodes* keywords and auto-flag the question to be reviewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no auto-flagging functionality like this. But if the spammer is using a particular URL very often, the URL can be blacklisted which will prevent the spam from being posted in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :)